# Is radial symmetry possible in texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

I saw a [technique](https://youtu.be/jAn7DxVtJsk?t=142) on YouTube that demonstrated radial symmetry in sculpt mode but can't find such settings in texture paint mode.

Is there a workaround for this in Blender? Why are both modes treated differently in that regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radial symmetry is a pretty new thing for Sculpt mode, and probably there hasn't been anyone that thought it was needed yet in Texture Paint mode. The operator would need to be reworked to use in Texture Paint, but as for a work around I don't know of one yet.